# How to build an abstract json unmarshaller in go

Tags: json, go

I have multiple APIs that follow a similar structure on the high level response. It always gives back an answer in that form:

```
{"data": {"feed":[{...}]}, "success": true}
```

However, the structure in Feed varies, depending on the concrete API.

I would now like to build an abstract function to process the various APIs. I have the following objects:

```
type SourceDTO struct { // top level object
    Success bool       `json:"success"`
    Data    Feed       `json:"data"`
}

type Feed struct {
    FeedData []<???> `json:"Feed"`
}
```

(The real object is more complex, but this shows the idea)

How would be a good way in go to parse this for the different APIs, ut having some common code with some logic based on the high level data (e.g. success)?

**EDIT:**
I am extending this, to explain more the extend of my question about the "pattern" I am looking for.

I want to create this package that parses the group of APIs. The DTO objects then have to be transferred into some other objects. These 'final' objects are defined in a different package (the entity package) and have then to be persisted.
I am now wondering, how to bring all this together: The 'finaly' entity objects, the transformation functions from DTO to entity, the parsing of the different APIs and their common and different result components.
Where do the transformation functions belong to (package wise)?

**EDIT2:** Specified FeedData to a slice after digging into the problem (see comments)

Comment: Have you considered using `interface{}` in place of `<???>`?

Comment: That would leave me with a map, which is basically handling a unstructured json, which is not what I want, because I know how the different concrete implementations look like.

Comment: Doesn't have to if you set the field's value before unmarshaling. Just like when you call json Unmarshal or Decode, you are passing a typed object to a function whose argument type is `interface{}`.

Comment: ... something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43325450/965900) is what I mean, it's not a duplicate I think but it might give you some ideas... Basically you work with your specific types, in their specific context, using type specific functions/methods. When you're done with the type-specific stuff you can set the `FeedData interface{}` with the result value and use the json package to turn that into the json response you want.

Comment: Thanks. I also played around with that option already. But the difference is that I have an array of data. Indeed I didn't specify that in my question (updated). When I try to apply your linked solution, I have the problem that I can not do a type assertion (cannot use _ (type []Customer) as type []interface {} in field value). Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Don't use `[]interface{}`. An `interface{}` can also hold a slice, so just keep the field's type `interface{}`, set the concrete slice type value to the field, and then you can do your type assertion. It will also be marshaled properly to json.

Comment: I created an example. It is not filled properly by unmarshal or am I doing something wrong? https://play.golang.org/p/TX4yhO-0i7e

Comment: Just like the `interface{}` argument that you're passing to `json.Unmarshal` as a pointer to the concrete type (`&dtoToSend`), so the value you set to the `Data interface{}` field *must* be a pointer. https://play.golang.org/p/nszWd2f3gZQ

Comment: ... and you have a typo in the json `"sucess"` instead of `"success"`, that's why the `Success` field stays `false`.

Comment: Awesome! Thank you! If you put all this in an answer, I would accept it. Otherwise I will 'self-answer', so the correct solution can be found easily.

Comment: Go ahead and write your answer, you know better how exactly you've applied the solution and i'll gladly upvote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @mkopriva for the input for this solution.

In order to have some abstraction in your json unmarshalling it is possible to use `interface{}` for many use cases.

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type UniversalDTO struct {
    Success bool        `json:"success"`
    Data    interface{} `json:"data"`
}

type ConcreteData struct {
    Source string `json:"source"`
    Site   string `json:"site"`
}

func main() {
    jsondata := []byte(`{"sucess":"true","data":[{"source":"foo","site":"bar"}]}`)

    data := make([]ConcreteData, 0, 10)
    dtoToSend := UniversalDTO{Data: &data}

    describe(dtoToSend)
    describe(dtoToSend.Data)

    json.Unmarshal(jsondata, &dtoToSend)

    describe(dtoToSend)
    describe(dtoToSend.Data)
}

func describe(i interface{}) {
    fmt.Printf("(%v, %T)\n", i, i)
}
```

Test here: https://play.golang.org/p/SSSp_zptMVN

`json.Unmarshal` expects an object into which the json is being put into. Thus, first we always need an object. Depending on the concrete instance of the target object, **the interface{} can be overriden with a concrete struct object** (which of course has to be created separately). An important learning here is, that a go **interface can also be overridden with a slice**. In this way, it is also possible to unmarshal an array into a go object. However, a slice of a struct has to be defined as a **slice of pointers** to that type.

Answer (score 1):

You can embed your `SourceDTO` struct into another struct, like this:

```
type SourceDTO struct { // top level object
    Success bool       `json:"success"`
}

type FeedResponse struct {
    FeedData YourCustomFeedStruct `json:"feed"`

    // Embedded Struct
    SourceDTO
}
```

Now you can access the `Success` bool from the FeedResponse struct. Also any methods defined on the `SourceDTO` struct can be accessed from the FeedResponse.

Comment: Okay. Then I would have a concrete struct for every concrete API, right? How would be the pattern to call an 'abstract' method with an API parameter to distinguish which type to use?

Comment: I just realize, that this will not create the same structure like I wrote in my question. You dont have SourceDTO.Data.FeedData